# Printing the succeed amount statement on if statement

Tags: java

I produced a ATM program on Java. Overall, it works. However, I'm trying to make it print "You are over the limit" when the user enter the succeed amount of both savings and checking. I used the if statement to do it. However, I'm not sure if it can produce the "You are over the limit" print. I'm new to learning Java so please be patient.

```
package atm;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class atm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int checking = 1000, savings = 5000, withdrawal = 0, deposit = 0;
        
        System.out.println("======================");
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to Sound Bank!");
        
        System.out.println("======================");
        
        while (true) {
        
        System.out.println("Please select which options: \n (C)Checking Balance \n (S)Savings");
        
        String choice1 = cin.nextLine(); 
        
        System.out.println("Please select of the following: ");
        
        System.out.println("(D)Deposit \n (W)Withdrawal \n (B)Check Balance \n (E)Exit");
        
        String choice2 = cin.nextLine(); 
        
        
            switch(choice2.toUpperCase()) {
            
            case "D":
                
                if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter your deposit amount:");
                    double num = cin.nextDouble();
                    double total = checking + num;
                    System.out.println("You entered" + num);
                    System.out.println("You have" + total);
                        if(num > checking) {
                            System.out.println("You are over the limit.");
                        }
                } else if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter your deposit amount");
                    double num1 = cin.nextDouble();
                    double total1 = savings + num1;
                    System.out.println("You entered" + num1);
                    System.out.println("You have" + total1);
                        if(num1 > savings) {
                            System.out.println("You are over the limit.");
                        }
                } 
                break;
            case "W":
                if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter your withdrawal amount:");
                    double w = cin.nextDouble();
                    double total2 = checking - w;
                    System.out.println("You entered" + w);
                    System.out.println("You have" + total2);
                        if(w > checking) {
                            System.out.println("You are over the limit.");
                        }
                } else if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter your withdrawal amount:");
                    double w2 = cin.nextDouble();
                    double total3 = cin.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("You entered " + w2);
                    System.out.println("You have" + total3);
                        if(w2 > savings) {
                            System.out.println("You are over the limit.");
                        }
                } 
                break;
            case "B": 
                if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                    double t1 = (checking + deposit) - withdrawal;
                    System.out.println("Your total amount is:" + t1);
                } else if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
                    double t2 = (savings + deposit) - withdrawal;
                    System.out.println("Your total amount is:" + t2);
                }
                break;
            case "E": 
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        
    
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What have you done to test this?

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I used Eclipse to run the test. I input 6000 withdrawal from the savings account, which is over the limit. I'm trying to print "You are over the limit". I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm trying to print out "You are over the limit" when the user input greater than the checking and savings account.

Comment: why you are taking user input for total3 ? shouldn't it be equal to savings - w2 ?

Comment: you haven't provided any logs, so asking you, is your code printing something after you are providing the amount ? or it's just waiting in blank screen ? if it is then that waiting is for that total3.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the input you're providing and the output your program produces.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. But I'm assuming your problem is over here

`double w2 = cin.nextDouble();`

`double total3 = cin.nextDouble();`

replace it with

`double w2 = cin.nextDouble();`

`double total3 = savings - w2;`

It should work as expected.